# UIImageview does not retain its round shape in static table view cell after getting image in it

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiimageview, uiimagepickercontroller

I want to set an image taken from gallery and camera in an imageview which is round in shape.But the shape of image view changes when I set the image to it.

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

//make imageview round
imageView.layer.cornerRadius = imageView.frame.size.width / 2;
imageView.clipsToBounds = YES;

UIImage *resizedImage=[Services resizeImage:image];
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

imageView.image=resizedImage;
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:true completion:nil];
```

[image]

thank you in advance

Comment: whats ur imageview frame

Comment: You need to set image view width and height fixed using auto layout.

Comment: I have set  height=80 ,width=80 and imageview is in center

Comment: Change contentMode. It's happen because of you are written imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

Comment: Open your debug view heirarchy and check the frame of the `UIImageView` being made, it ought to still be a circle even after setting the image. Probably image is getting resized improperly.

Comment: hide this line and try once UIImage *resizedImage=[Services resizeImage:image];\

Comment: what @Maddy said is right. You need to change it to imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik said is right. you need to hid this line UIImage *resizedImage=[Services resizeImage:image];  and use to imageView.image=image;

Comment: thanks...imageView maintains its shape for scale type Aspect Fill for images coming from camera and gallery. Now I'm extending the functionality of my app, want to load image from server and this time imageView shape get changed to rectangle or square

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set your image view frame as a square then set Corner radius half of the width.See these lines -

```
 userimage.layer.borderWidth = 3.0
    userimage.clipsToBounds = true
    userimage.layer.cornerRadius = userimage.frame.size.width / 2;
    userimage.layer.borderColor = UIColor.orangeColor().CGColor
```

Here user image size is 50*50.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be selecting "tall" image. 
Replace

`imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;`

With

`imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;`

so that it covers entire area and you will be able to see that it's rounded.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do the opposite: crop the image to a circle, and add it to a square view:

```
CALayer *imageLayer = image.layer;
[imageLayer setCornerRadius:image.frame.size.width/2];
[imageLayer setBorderWidth:1];
[imageLayer setMasksToBounds:YES];
imageLayer.borderColor = (__bridge CGColorRef _Nullable)([UIColor clearColor]);
```

Answer (score 0):

first make sure your imageView aspect ratio is 1:1

and set cornerRadius of imageView after you set resized picture.